# OSX Lion - cannot remove imagick

Tags: homebrew, imagick, rmagick

I am trying to remove `imagick`, it's installed via `brew`.
If I run `brew remove imagick` or `brew uninstall imagick`, I get

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/imagick
```

How to fix it? Google didn't really help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to run

```
brew doctor
```

and follow the instructions. Hope that will fix it.

Comment: Well, I tried to follow those steps, but it still didn't work for me. I tried to link the library: `brew link --overwrite imagemagick` and got `Linking /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10... Warning: Could not link imagemagick. Unlinking...

Error: Permission denied - /usr/local/etc/ImageMagick/type.xml` ...how to fix the issue with permissions?

Comment: Brew need `/usr/local` to be owned by you. You can fix this with ```sudo chown -R `whoami` /usr/local```.